# Specialization of member function of a template class in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I would like to create a template class foo, and have one of its member function test() be specialized according to the template type of foo. M first attempt was to include the code in the header file defining foo:

```
template<typename Type>
class foo
{
    foo()
    ~foo()
    test()
};

template<>
foo<float>::test()
{ code ... };
```

The problem is that if I compile and link multiple files using this header, I get an error of multiple definition.

I also tried to declare the specialization in the header, so the compiler knows it should not generate the templated code. I then put the specialized definition in a separate C++ file to be compiled. The header then looked like:

```
template<typename Type>
class foo
{
    foo()
    ~foo()
    test()
};

template<>
foo<float>::test();
```

But I then got an undefined reference error.

How should I organize the declaration and definition of the specialized member function ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the *declaration* in the header file, and the *definition* in a source file.

Since the function is fully specified by the declaration, the definition can be in any translation unit. linked with the application.

Or make the function definition `inline` in the header file.

Comment: Thank you. I found out that my error in the second case came from not defining the destructor.